# Drop down menu showing different reviews

Tags: html, css

I want to systematize the product reviews on my website. My goal is to create feature like on Amazon. See the screenshot below:

https://ibb.co/fSXjFFd

where to have a drop-down menu - "Most recent", "Top reviews", and etc categories.

Can someone give me an example or tell me where to find information on how to create such a drop-down menu?

My idea is first to create static HTML code, there will be hardcoded reviews of different categories.

After understand how things work with pure HTML in the future, I'll extend the functionality with PHP which to take the texts of different reviews from the SQL database.

Comment: If you're new to web development, spend some time on this site learning HTML, CSS, JS, etc https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way should be with CSS styling.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  background: #eee;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" target="_self">Link to first</a>
    <a href="#" target="_self">Link to second</a>
  </div>
</div>
```